# Python Beautiful soup: Target a particular element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a particular part of a website(https://flightmath.com/from-CDG-to-BLR) but I am unable to target the element that I need.

### Below is the part of the html

`<h2 style="background-color:#7DC2F8;padding:10px"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i>
&nbsp;flight distance = <strong>4,866</strong> miles</h2>`

### This is my code

```
dist = soup.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'fa fa-plane'})
```

I just want to target the "4,866" part.

I would be really grateful if someone can guide me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about this `dist = soup.select_one('h2 > strong').text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs={'class': '...'}` requires an exact `class` attribute value (not a combination). 
Instead, use `soup.select_one` method to select by extended `css` rule:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://flightmath.com/from-CDG-to-BLR'
html_data = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

dist = soup.select_one('h2 i.fa-plane + strong')
print(dist.text)   # 4,866
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of interest: The value is hard coded into the html (for a flight speed calculation) so you could also regex out a more precise value with the following. You can use `round()` to get the value shown on page.

```
import requests, re

urls = ['https://flightmath.com/from-CDG-to-BOM', 'https://flightmath.com/from-CDG-to-BLR', 'https://flightmath.com/from-CDG-to-IXC']
p = re.compile(r'flightspeed\.min\.value\/60 \+ ([0-9.]+)')
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        print(p.findall(s.get(url).text)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

find  tag with class name and then use find_next() to find the strong tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://flightmath.com/from-CDG-to-BLR'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
dist = soup.find('i',class_='fa-plane').find_next('strong')
print(dist.text)
```